# v-select testing with cypress

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

help how can i test vuetify version 3's v-select using cypress version 12 am finding it impossible to select an option in my tests thanks

```
<v-select
  v-model="country"
  :items="['UG', 'KE', 'TZ']"
  variant="outlined"
  data-cy="country"
  label="Dam Id*"
  :rules="[required]"
  required
></v-select>

 cy.get([data-cy="country"]).type(`UG{enter}`, { force: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cy.get('[data-cy="country"]').click().type(`UG{downarrow}{enter}`)
cy.get('[data-cy="country"]').find('input').should('have.value', 'UG')
```

and maybe add cy.wait(SOMEVALUE) if it didn't work